# Python - ¿Cómo escribir un campo en un archivo CSV de manera que Excel lea #N/A?

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, csv

La pregunta se refiere sobre todo a qué hacer ante la falta de un dato.

¿Cómo rellenar en Excel esas celdas -indicando *explícitamente* que falta un dato, es decir: no dejándolas en blanco?

En Python existe `None`; en Pandas tenemos incluso `NaN` pero, ¿cómo hacer que estos valores sean leídos correctamente por Excel?

Se podría utilizar `pandas`, aunque preferiría el módulo `csv` integrado en la librería estándar.

Gracias por sus sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias en realidad a una vulnerabilidad de Excel que se conoce como [inyección de formulas](http://georgemauer.net/2017/10/07/csv-injection.html), es totalmente posible hacer esto, incluso en un `csv` que por su naturaleza representa datos pasivos.

La idea sería usar las función `NOD()` que retorna un valor "No disponible", `#N/A` o `#N/D`  según el idioma. Es tan simple como especificar la formula en el archivo `csv`:

```
C1,C2
1,2
2,=NOD()
```

Obviamente, esto no parece un "feature", por lo que eventualmente algún día tal vez deje de funcionar.